# NoSuchMethodError exception in uber jar

Tags: scala, maven, selenium, ssl, apache-spark

These are [dependencies](https://gist.github.com/fahadsiddiqui/90420f5fc344596988f4a4c5217c32a5#file-pom-xml) inside is my `pom.xml` file. When I run Driver from my maven project as a Scala application, it works fine. But when I create a `jar-with-dependency` and try to run my project through `spark-submit`

```
spark-submit --class package.signature.Driver --master local[*] /path/to/my/jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I get following exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:125)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.buildSSLSocketFactory(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:112)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.configureHttpsScheme(HttpWebConnection.java:597)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.createHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:532)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getHttpClientBuilder(HttpWebConnection.java:494)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:158)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1321)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1238)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:346)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:415)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:541)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:530)

Origin of this exception is `.getPageSource` from the code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import org.apache.spark.Logging

object Selenium extends Logging {
  val driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(false)
  val implicitWaitTimeout = 30 // seconds
  driver.manage.timeouts.implicitlyWait(implicitWaitTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  def getPageSource(urlPage: String): String = {
    driver.get(urlPage)
    driver.getPageSource
  }
}
```

What I have tried so far.
Trying to exclude multiple versions of `apache-httpcomponent`. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a transitive dependency problem, it means that you have jars which have this class each having version of that class where this method is not present  and by default maven loads that class which it gets first, you can check the class by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, you can see multiple versions of that class, once you find the class which will not be having that method, in `pom.xml` for that `.jar` which contains that file write exclusion for that.

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Shift+T` where?

Comment: In Eclipse in your project e.g to search some file we use Ctrl+Shift+R, similarly use Ctrl+Shift+T to search all the source files in all jars

Answer (score 1):

From exception it appears that **selenium-htmlunit-driver** (conclusion from seeing `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit` in exception) cannot find **org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient v. 4.4 or higher** (conclusion from looking up in which package [SSLConnectionSocketFactory](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.html) is; more specifically it wants version 4.4 or above of this lib, since the method it cannot find is introduced in version 4.4,see [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.html#SSLConnectionSocketFactory(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier))). Also if you look at [dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver/2.52.0) of selenium-htmlunit-driver, it looks like it's using version 4.5.1. So include the following into your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

so that it packages this lib with your JAR. And of course make sure you don't have another `httpclient-x.x.x.jar` in the same folder.

Comment: i tried the solution you mentioned above. it didn't work.
there were multiple inclusions of httpclient. i tried excluding all other `httpclient` versions using `exclusions` in pom dependency. that didn't work either.